# Access a computer in another network via web browser

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, ssh-tunnel

I have a Windows machine (computer 1) that is connected to a Windows server (computer 2) 192.9.100.10

The Windows server has connectivity to an internal web server (computer 3) - 192.168.100.200

From my Windows device (computer 1) I do not have connectivity to (computer 3) 192.168.100.200

My target is to access the computer 3 as https://192.168.100.200:443 from computer 1 web browser.

So I do the following steps:

I use putty and create a tunnel to establish an RDP connection from computer 1 to computer 2 via port 22

In the forward port in the putty I set that putty

```
 L1000               192.9.100.10:3389
```

The connection from computer 1 to the Windows server (computer 2) was successful and I have accessed computer 2 remotely.

From computer 2, what Windows feature or functionality will let me open up a tunnel to allow computer 1 access the internal web server (computer 3) via the web browser like https://192.168.100.200?

Remark - software installation is not permitted on the Windows server (computer 2) however, any software can be installed on computer 1.
Remark - Windows firewall is enabled!

Comment: The network is a /24 ? if so, ask your network admin to unlock your firewall please. Bypassing security set in place by your netadmin is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes it's is a /24. However, we're trying to explore and see if they'll be any way to leave the firewall and software installation rules unchanged and achieve the aim above.